# How to synchronous an observable

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs

I have an issue in synchronising the observable, I couldn't figure out how to fix it. this is my code so far:
service:

```
getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortal(layer: number, target: TargetAciInput): Observable<CatalogueCategoryType[]> {
    return this.getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortalGQL
      .fetch({ layer, target })
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response.data.getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortal));
  }
 getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortals(
    layer: number,
    target: TargetAciInput,
    parent: string,
  ): Observable<CatalogueCategoryType[]> {
    return this.getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortalGQL
      .fetch({ layer, target, parent })
      .pipe(map((response: any) => response.data.getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortal));
  }
```

NgOnInit:

```
    this.appService.getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortal(1, { pos: '' }).subscribe((res: any) => {
      res.forEach((element) => {
        this.catalogueCategorieLayer1.push(element);
        this.appService.getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortals(2, { pos: '' }, this.parentId).subscribe((response: any) => {
          this.catalogueCategorieLayer2 = [...this.catalogueCategorieLayer2, response];
          console.log('1');
        });
        console.log('2', this.catalogueCategorieLayer2);
        this.hasChildren = element.hasChildren;
      });
    });
    this.appService.getCatalogueCategoriesByLayerAndParentForPortals(3, { pos: '' }, this.parentId2).subscribe((response: any) => {
      response.forEach((element) => {
        this.catalogueCategorieLayer3[0] = element.name;
      });
    });
  }
```

the problem is the console.log("2") is excuted before console.log("1")

Answer (score 0):

You can use concat( [observable1, observable2] ) to make sure the 1st observable finishes before calling the next observable.

You have to move the logic from the subscribe() to the pipe() of the observables.

Comment: This is correct, but as a side note: never ever Nest subscriptions, you open up the Gates of hell aka memory leaks and unforseeable behavior. Trust me, I had to fix some code like that which made the website unusable in a couple of seconds. Operators are there to actually prevent you from nesting ;)